# Replace default android media volume toast

Tags: android

My requirement is to replace the default volume toast with a customized one.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think that this is doable. HTC is doing that in Sense but I think they edit the OS directly.

Second, you **should really not do this**, even if it was possible. Users expect given UI elements to be consistent across the operating system. Custom UI elements that replace the system-provided interface always break the platform experience.

Comment: So it is not possible to hide the volume toast when my application is running?

Comment: You didn't mention this crucial "when my application is running" before. :-) Try sony's answer as your activity's keyboard handler.

Comment: Before posting the issue I had tried with that code.But the volume toast is displayed.I just want to hide that toast and show my own volume level indicator

Comment: Issue solved I just add return true instead of return false in sony's code

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // Or use adjustStreamVolume method.
        am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // Or use adjustStreamVolume method.
        am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a customized Toast Class by extending Built in Toast class. I haven't yet tried it must be easy and impractical.
Take a look at this..:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

And this:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-toast-tutorial

Comment: I don't want to make a customized toast class.I want to show my own widget when the user presses the volume buttons.That means I want to hide the default volume toast